# Compilation errors when number of member function template arguments exceeds 1

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Would someone kindly tell me why the complier flags an error when I attempt to call the versions of the member function `Foo<T>::setValue` that involve more than 1 template argument, as shown below.

See [ideone](http://ideone.com/cvqOQ)

```
class Bar
{
public:
    enum TYPE{};
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename P>
    void setValue1();

    template<typename P, int>
    void setValue2();

    template<typename P, typename P::TYPE>
    void setValue3();

private:
    T   m_value;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
template<typename P>
void Foo<T>::setValue1()
{
}

template<typename T>
template<typename P, int>
void Foo<T>::setValue2()
{
}

template<typename T>
template<typename P, typename P::TYPE>
void Foo<T>::setValue3()
{
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    Foo<Bar::TYPE> f1;

    f1.setValue1<Bar>();                // Compiles
    f1.setValue2<Bar, int>();       // ERROR
    f1.setValue3<Bar, Bar::TYPE>(); // ERROR

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

GCC error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo<Bar::TYPE>::setValue2()’
error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo<Bar::TYPE>::setValue3()’
```

MSVC .NET 2008 error:

```
Test6.cpp(60) : error C2975: 'Foo<T>::setValue2' : invalid template argument for 'unnamed-parameter', expected compile-time constant expression
        with
        [
            T=Bar::TYPE
        ]
        Test6.cpp(24) : see declaration of 'Foo<T>::setValue2'
        with
        [
            T=Bar::TYPE
        ]
Test6.cpp(61) : error C2975: 'Foo<T>::setValue3' : invalid template argument for 'unnamed-parameter', expected compile-time constant expression
        with
        [
            T=Bar::TYPE
        ]
        Test6.cpp(27) : see declaration of 'Foo<T>::setValue3'
        with
        [
            T=Bar::TYPE
        ]
```

Comment: They don't take any arguments in the declaration either... I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve with this code.. Can you please specify?

Comment: Thank you for pasting the errors you got, they're really helpful.

Comment: @Martol1ni In my production code all `Foo<T>::setValue`'s accept strings. I was hoping that each method would treat the string input differently and set the `m_value` accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I addition to the problem @Jason mentioned, your second function template takes an `int` as its second argument, and you are providing a type.

This was fixed by changing the name to `setValue2` per @Jason's post, then changing the function call to:

```
f1.setValue2<Bar, 3>();
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the third template function definition.  It seems you should only need one template argument, since P::Type can also be derived.

I should also note that your class definition is not really precise -- the class's template argument is a `typename`, but you're passing it `Bar::TYPE` which is an `enum` type.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot overload a function in C++ based on template arguments ... you can only overload functions based on the function argument signature.

Comment: I've renamed the methods but am still getting the same errors. See link in OP.